# Why the GITHUB Plugin Jenkins doesn't show up in Jenkins configuration?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to GIT and looking for some help. In Jenkins UI, I can see that it shows GIT plug-in is installed but I cannot see it in edit conjuration page.
When I see in the backend I can see 2 files:

- `github.jpi`
- `github.jpi.disable`

Do I need to remove the `.disable` file, can you help me how to proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a `xxx.jpi.disable` file disable a plugin.
Try remove it and see if the issue persists.

But check also if the [Jenkins GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) wasn't removed in the first place because of missing dependencies.
It depends on:

- [ssh-agent](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) (version:1.3)
- [github-api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+API+Plugin) (version:1.42)
- [git](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) (version:2.0)
- [git-client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) (version:1.4.4)
- [multiple-scms](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) (version:0.2, optional)
- [credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) (version:1.8.3)
- [ssh-credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin) (version:1.5.1)
- [scm-api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+API+Plugin) (version:0.1)

Check that those plugins are indeed installed, with the right version.